# View transactions on a test credit card in PayPal sandbox account

Tags: testing, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am currently testing paypal integration on my website. I have created PayPal sandbox account, both merchant and buyer.
Each buyer account has an associated credit card with it. When I use that card to pay for the goods, my test merchant account receives money, however buyers account doesn't reflect that money were withdrawn.

I guess this is because PayPal will only show transactions on you PayPal account but not on your credit card. I wonder if there is a way to see the transaction on the test credit card.